# "illegal instructions core dumped message" error occurs when I try to open jupyter notebook from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

[image]

This was not happening the first time. The same error occurred when I ran the streamlit app and for the solution of streamlit, I modified bash. After restarting Ubuntu, nothing was solved even jupyter notebook stopped working.

- Ubuntu with KDE Desktop
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 5.19.0-32-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Processors: 4 × AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
- Memory: 7.2 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: AMD SUMO

I tried a solution which was about installing pipenv but that did not work.